# Check if a group of signals have a significantly lower or higher value from another group using GLM

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model

I have a question that is a kinda puzzling me and hope that I can find some answers here :).

Suppose I have many signals, let's say four $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$

Suppose I have a set of windows $w_1, w_2, \dots , w_n $, in each window each signal follow a Poisson distribution, i.e: $ X_i \sim Poisson(\lambda_i) $.

What I want to do is to find windows that show a high value for some signals and not for others, for example they have high value for $X_1, X_2$ and low signal for $X_3, X_4$

One idea that come to my mind is to use an ANOVA-like method in which the first group contains $ X_1, X_2$ and the second contains $ X_3, X_4$ and test if the values of group are significantly **bigger**  or **lower** than the other.

Because the data is not normally distributed I thought of using a GLM model how ever it seems that existing glm package in R and python test for equality (hope to be wrong).

Does this approach seem reasonable ? if so how to perform this test using R or python statsmodel package.

Comment: How are you identifying which windows to use to put into the ANOVA?

Comment: The size of the windows in not unique. they are determined after using some software. My input then are the windows and for each window I have the values for the different type of networks. each signal is normalized

Comment: How is the *software* choosing the windows, then? How are the windows chosen? How do you end up having windows where you didn't at the beginning - what procedure is followed in which you end up with some window?

Comment: Can you post some example data?

Comment: to be more specific, I have a chip-Seq signal (which indicated the strength of binding of a protein with DNA), then the software tries to find the regions in the genome with significant peak, using a certain Bayesian model (they suppose that the distributions follow a poisson distribution). At the end, you get the genomic coordinates (for example chromosome 1, from 100, 200 with a signal of 10, ... etc for all other regions)
I do that for different proteins. than use the windows of one signal of interest as reference . hope it is clear

Comment: @Henrik, you can imaging that for each window $w$ we have $N$ numeric verctor of length $L_w$ and we want to test if some vectors have a significant hight value than the rest